# How to exclude the occurence of alpha char at the end the string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a set of list of movies which is like this

```
Name: The Godfather: Part II (1974) 1080p 
Genre:  Crime | Drama 
rating:  9.1/10
```

Now what I want to achieve is to get the movie name till the year 
that is `The Godfather: Part II`

however while making the regular expression its always taking the last p in the name string

what  I am doing is

```
r=re.compile(r"[^a-zA-Z :]")
```

and then

```
r.sub("",Name)
```

the result is coming as

```
The Godfather: Part II  p
```

Now my question is how do I exclude the alpha char at the end by regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print re.findall(r"^(.+?)(?=\(\d{4}|\d{4})",Name)
```

You are better of trying to match than removing unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

`re.search` or `re.findall` is the way to go.

```
>>> Name = "The Godfather: Part II (1974) 1080p "
>>> re.findall(r'(.*?)\s+\(\d{4}\)', Name)
['The Godfather: Part II']
>>> re.search(r'(.*?)\s+\(\d{4}\)', Name).group(1)
'The Godfather: Part II'
```

If you want to use `re.sub`, then match all the characters from the year upto to the last.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s+\(\d{4}\).*', r'', Name)
'The Godfather: Part II'
```